# For $f : \mathbb{R} \stackrel{\text{cont.}}{\to} \mathbb{R}$, show that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)x^2\,dx = \frac{1}{3}f(c)$ for some $c \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> For $f : \mathbb{R} \stackrel{\text{cont.}}{\to} \mathbb{R}$, show that $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)x^2 \,dx= \frac{1}{3}f(c)$$ for some $c \in [0,1]$.

I have seen similar problems that Rolle's theorem or LMVT can solve neatly. This one seems to have a scalar of $\frac{1}{3}$ attached with it, which screams of $x^2$ being integrated somewhere.

Comment: Note that you can't use IBP because we only assumed $f$ continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the following fact: if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $g$ is integrable and nonnegative on $[a,b]$, then there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that:
$$\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,dx=f(c)\int_a^bg(x)\,dx.$$
(I can give the proof, but it's not too difficult if you want to try by yourself first.)

Comment: I believe this is by IVT. $f(x)$ is continuous and $m \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)dx \leq M \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx$ where $m = \displaystyle\inf_{x \in [a,b]} \{f(x) \}, M = \displaystyle\sup_{x \in [a,b]} \{f(x) \}$. Helps, I appreciate the hint.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The IVT is the crux of the proof. Glad this helps.